# Example of a variety with explicit cohomology ring and Kahler cone

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I'm looking for some fairly explicit varieties to use as (counter?-)examples for my thesis and I'd appreciate any suggestions. I need a smooth projective variety $X$ of general type that satisfies:

- The Hodge number $h^{1,1}$ is at least 2.
- The cohomology ring of $X$ (or at least the subring generated by $(1,1)$-classes) is explicit.
- The Kahler cone of $X$ is known(-ish).

I want to calculate the sectional curvatures of the Riemannian metric on the Kahler cone of $X$ which is defined by the intersection product. These curvatures may be expressed by the intersection product on the subring $A$ of $H^*(X)$ genereated by degree $(1,1)$ classes, which explains the conditions I impose.

The condition on the Hodge number is necessary, since when $h^{1,1} = 1$ one ends up with the metric $g(x,y)(t) = xy/t$ on the half-line $\mathbb R_+$ and not many interesting things remain unsaid about this case. This excludes most hypersurfaces in $\mathbb P^n$, except perhaps for those in $\mathbb P^3$.

I must also exclude the example of a blowup of several points of a variety $X$ with $h^{1,1} = 1$, since one can calculate explicitly what happens in this case. Are there other relatively easy examples?

Comment: What does "knownish" mean?

Comment: Like pornography, I'll know it when I see it. What I have in mind is that maybe I don't have to describe exactly the Kahler cone in $H^{1,1}(X)$, but only know some open set that is definitely in the cone.

Comment: non-general K3 surfaces ?  I'm not familiar with the literature, but I think this must be known in many cases.  If all of $h^{1,1} is algebraic, that should work- no ?

Comment: and i missed 'general type in my first reading' sorry.

Comment: Why don't you use a general type hypersurface (or complete intersection) in $\mathbb{P}^a \times \mathbb{P}^b$, or in any toric variety of whatever Picard number you like?  If the dimension is at least 3, then you can use the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem to describe the Kaehler cone.  Of course you can use adjunction to insure the variety is of general type.

Answer (score 3):

You could look at surfaces with maximal Picard rank. A surface is said to have maximal Picard rank if $H^{1,1}(X) \cap H^1(X, \mathbb{R})$ is spanned by curve classes. So the Kahler cone is the same as the ample cone, and you can compute the intersection pairing on $H^{1,1}$ by just intersecting curves with each other.

Now, this raises the question of whether there is a surface of general type with maximal Picard rank. Some googling found me the following:

Section 3 of [Quintic surfaces with maximum and other Picard numbers](http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.3519) shows that the Fermat sextic $w^6+x^6+y^6+z^6=0$ has maximal Picard rank. Apparently, this was originally computed by Beauville.

[Roulleau shows](http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.4855) that there are infinitely many Fano surfaces with maximal Picard rank, and gives a basis for the Neron-Severi group. (Confusingly, the [Fano surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_surface) is not a Fano variety, but rather is of general type.)

<strike>A warning: If you look at [this paper](http://www.springerlink.com/content/g55236l64258418w/) or [this one](http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.3519), they compute a lot of surfaces with maximal Picard. However, their method is to make a surface with an $A_n$ singularity and prove that its resolution has maximal Picard. Since this resolution has a $-2$ curve, it is automatically not of general type.</strike> Sorry. As Donu says, I was confused. $K$ will not be ample, but it will be big, and the varieties are general type.

I was coming back to edit in one more idea -- if $C$ is the [Klein quartic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_quartic), then I think that $C \times C$ has maximal Picard rank. But Jason Starr's comment is simpler than any of my suggestions.

Comment: How does having a $-2$ curve make a surface not of general type?

Comment: David, I think you mean that $K$ won't be ample thanks
to the $-2$ curves; Persson's examples are certainly of general
type.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any snapshot saved on the Wayback Machine. (But perhaps it does not matter so much, since the link is behind text that has been struck out.)